# SQL connecting with C# and visual studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been trying to learn c#, I tried this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C, and I'm still confused.

I'm trying to figure out what the basic code is to connect to a database with C#. I haven't created the database yet. I'm just looking for some basic code to make a connection... maybe some code to connect to an already existing database.

The general format of the code is this:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + 
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" + 
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                       "database=database; " + 
                                       "connection timeout=30");
```

Is that right? Does anyone have a good primer for SQL and C#? If this is too advanced, what's a good resource to begin learning?

Comment: First you need to plug in your sql server information into the connection string. Your username, server address, and db.

Comment: To add to Chris' comment, do you have a database setup somewhere, and can you reach it through a database GUI program? For example, if you have a MySQL database setup, can you reach it through a program like MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL? You won't be able to connect via C# until you can do this.

Comment: Also, you either need: Trusted_Connection OR a username and password

Comment: Learning how to "access SQL" requires that you learn an API that provides the programmers interface between his applcation and the RDBMS system.  In Java, this API is called JDBC but other higher level mechanisms for database access exist as well (eg. JPA).  You need to focus on learning the API that you need to use in C#.

Comment: You cannot connect to a database that you haven't created yet ....

Comment: Can someone upvote my changes so I can post again? I'm new to coding and I'm trying to learn and ask questions that are as specific as possible... but it's tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to learn the core of ADO.NET first and not just pasting code from the web.

I Recommend this tutorial from C# Station.

[C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial.](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet)

Best Regards

Comment: ADO.NEt is the technology used in any languages like c# and vb to connect to any data base and perform its full functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the comments. I found a few good primers for Python and so I'm going to start there. Thanks again for your help. I've edited my posts... can someone upvote so I can get unblocked please? I've also begun taking courses in Python and reading ADO.NET tutorials. I'd like to get my account unblocked please.